# Perl: to compare two files in perl

Tags: perl

I am relatively new to scripting. I would like to understand how to compare two files.

File 1:

```
abc 
cde
fgh
```

File 2:

```
cde  dummy
abc  dummy
fgh  dummy
```

I want to compare the first two columns in two files and print that if the file matches or it does not. I do not want to use awk, diff or cut.

Just trying to use it through perl. Can anyone please share me the algorithm so that I will try to code it.

Comment: I have started learning scripting now, if you can add a small piece of code, it will help me understand and learn it in detail.

Comment: Your description of the problem is confusing. Sample has different content of the files -- **dummy** is not present in first file. Do you want compare first column of each file? What you consider as _different_? If first _mismatch_ takes place then should the files be considered as different? Or you want to see what lines do not present in second file? Or you want to see lines missing in first file from second and lines missing in second file from first file?

Comment: Do you consider the files as different if order of the lines do not match but otherwise content is the same?

Comment: I want to compare the first column of the two files.Second file has two columns. I do not want to consider it as different if the order of lines are different. Even if the order of lines are different I should do a compare.

Comment: The example given in my question should result in perfect match even if the line orders are different. Thanks for the response Polar Bear!!

Comment: I understand that you want a set of unique strings from column one of the first file, the same for second file and check if those sets are the same. Right?

Comment: Hi Ramiro, Yes perfect! that is what I want. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Function that get a name file from input
# and returns a hash where keys are the
# first column per row.
sub populateHash {

    my %hash;

    open my $file, '<', @_;

    # Read the file row by row.
    while (my $row = <$file>) {

        # Delete the row end of line.
        chomp($row); 

        # Ignores if the row is empty.
        if ( $row =~ /^$/ ) { next; } 

        # Get the first column of the row.
        my ($column1) = $row =~ /^(\w+)/;

        # Put the first column $column1 as key in the hash.
        # If the key in the hash already exists, 
        # don't duplicate keys (the keys are unique in a hash).
        # Set the value of the key $column1 to '' (is not relevant).
        $hash{$column1} = '';  
    }  

    close $file;

    return %hash;
}

# Populating hashes for both files 
# calling populateHash function
# with the filename as param.
my %file1 = populateHash("file1.txt");
my %file2 = populateHash("file2.txt");

# Getting the number of elements of both files hashes.
$sizeFile1 = keys %file1;
$sizeFile2 = keys %file2;

# If the number of keys in the hash are not the same, 
# the elements not match, exit.
if ($sizeFile1 ne $sizeFile2) { die "Number of elements not match.\n"};

# Iterates all keys of file1 hash.
foreach my $key (keys %file1) {

    # If key in file1 hash not exists in file2 hash, exit.
    if ( not exists $file2{$key} ) { 

        die "Elements not match.\n"     
    } 
}

# If all keys in file1 hash exists in file2, all the elements match!
print "Elements match!\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can module `Array::Utils` to find the `Matched` and `Unmatched` two arrays

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

#Passing the files as an arguments  
my $file1 = $ARGV[0]; my $file2 = $ARGV[1];

#Declaring variables
my ($file1cnt, $file2cnt, @arr1, @arr2) = ""; 

#reading the file 1 and storing in variable
readFileinString($file1,\$file1cnt);  

#reading the file 2 and storing in another variable
readFileinString($file2,\$file2cnt);  

#Find and Storing the values in array 1
push (@arr1, $1), while($file1cnt=~m/^([^\n]+)$/gm);

#Find the first column and Storing the values in array 2
push (@arr2, $1), while($file2cnt=~m/^([^\t]+)\t([^\n]+)$/gm);

#using the module functions `sub routines` to find the difference and sequence
my @unmatched_arr = array_diff(@arr1, @arr2);
my @matched_arr = unique(@arr1, @arr2);

print join "\n", @matched_arr;


#------------------>Reading a file
sub readFileinString
#------------------>
{
    my $File = shift;
    my $string = shift;
    use File::Basename;
    my $filenames = basename($File);

    open(FILE1, "<$File") or die "\nFailed Reading File: [$File]\n\tReason: $!";
    read(FILE1, $$string, -s $File, 0);
    close(FILE1);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Dumping just code on someone who already doesn't know how to do it doesn't help that much. They still don't know how to do it even if they can run your program and get the output. It's a much better answer if you explain the approach and techniques you use so they understand why it works. :)

Comment: @briandfoy: Sure I will do better from onwards, however on this case I have little bit explain on my comments as well right?

Comment: Well, the comments say what the code is doing, which the code already tells you, like your comment for the subroutine.  Furthermore, some of your comments don't match up with the code.

Comment: Ok.. I will focus on this one...

Answer (score -2):

One of many possible approaches to solution of described problem

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

usage() if $#ARGV != 1;         # we expect two filenames on command line

my $fname1 = shift;             # get first filename
my $fname2 = shift;             # get second filename

my $f1 = read_file($fname1);    # read file 1 into a hash
my $f2 = read_file($fname2);    # read file 2 into a hash

my $f1_size = keys %{$f1};      # count number of keys for file 1
my $f2_size = keys %{$f2};      # count number of keys for file 2

die "INFO: files are different on keys size in column 1"
        unless $f1_size == $f2_size;

for (keys %{$f1}) { info_finish($fname2,$_) if not defined $f2->{$_}; }
for (keys %{$f2}) { info_finish($fname1,$_) if not defined $f1->{$_}; }

say "INFO: files match";

exit;

sub usage {
    __FILE__ =~ m!([^\\]+)$!;

    my $prog_name = $1;

    say 
"
    $prog_name  Two file comparison script  May1, 2020

    USAGE: $prog_name filename1 filename2

           Please provide two filenames on command line
";

    exit;
}

sub read_file {
    my $fname = shift;

    my %hash;

    open my $fh, '<', $fname
        or die "Can't open $fname: $!";

    while( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;
        $hash{$1}=$_ if /^(\S+)/;
    }

    close $fh;

    return \%hash;
}

sub info_finish {
    my $fname = shift;
    my $key   = shift;

    say "INFO: $fname is missing '$key' key in first column";

    exit;
}
```